# Gson: Get an array of objects which is nested in an object, which in turn is nested in an entire JSON object

Tags: java, json, android-sqlite

**Edit**

I'd love to hear any solution. It doesn't have to be with Gson. Also, if you know a good tutorial about parsing nested JSON, I'd love if you would tell me its name or provide a link.

How many SQLite table are required? as of now I have one table. Does every nested object requires a table?

**The original question**

I'm trying to get this nested array of objects with Gson. I tried using TypeToken but I couldn't find the rules on how to inplement TypeToken (such rules might have helped in using TypeToken for a specific JSON).

**The JSON**

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "episodes":[
      {
        "name": "Probe",
        "summary": "adasdasdas"
      },
      {...},
      {...}
      ]
   }
}
```

**What I tried**:

```
// inserting the JSON to SQLite
    private void insertToSQLite(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Episode>>(){}.getType();
        List<Episode> episodesList = gson.fromJson(output, listType);

        for(Episode episode : episodesList) {

            ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();

            insertValues.put(Episode.ID, episode.getId());
            insertValues.put(Episode.TITLE, episode.getTitle());
            insertValues.put(Episode.SUMMARY, episode.getSummary());
...
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.reflect.TypeParameter;
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class TestJson {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = "{\"_embedded\": { \"episodes\":[{\"name\": \"Probe\",\"summary\": \"adasdasdas\" }]}}";
    JsonElement jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject().get("_embedded").getAsJsonObject()
            .get("episodes");
    Type listType = setModelAndGetCorrespondingList(Episode.class);
    List<Episode> episodes = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, listType);

    System.out.println(episodes);
}

private static <T> Type setModelAndGetCorrespondingList(Class<T> type) {
    return new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {
    }.where(new TypeParameter<T>() {
    }, type).getType();
}
```

}